# How to get into recovery mode if -

Tags: boot-loop, volume-control

- My both volume keys are broken
- the phone is stuck in a boot loop
  while playing a game and using game guardian to hack it my battery died and when i started it this sh*t happened.
  so no use of cable and adb as soon as i connect battery and press power button the screen lits up for 1 sec and no result but when i connect charger the phone start and the foll. text appears
- Powered by- android
- micromax bolt

and the the processes repeats itself.

Is this fault of rooting or game guardian (for precaution)

please help.

Comment: Well that things happens when you hack games :P Since volume buttons are broken and phone is in bootloop I don't think it's possible to get to recovery or download mode or else. Fix volume keys and then try to fix bootloop by flashing rom/firmware.

Comment: Which Micromax  Bolt model is that? please provide more informations if you need help

Answer (score 0):

Unless your device has a save switch to put it in download mode without using physical keys, you are stuck in this.

Some devices can be forced to download mode by shorting specific circuit.
You can also try to short the volume button to make it appear it is pressed.